# Getting Information from a website, change the information language to English and insert them to database

Tags: database, algorithm, sqlite, translation, sql-insert

I am trying to insert information into my database, which is in Spanish and I want them in English, but it takes me so long to copy the text from a website and translate it into English and then to insert it into my database with a specific structure for the text. Is there any idea or algorithmic possibility to make all this thing easier to do and to take shorter time?

Answer (score -1):

Write a **scraper** which gets the contents, if there is some structure available. Then translate it with something like this:
https://github.com/chriskonnertz/DeepLy
The quality of Translations from deepl.com is in my opinion really good, assumed the input text has no grammar/spelling errors.

Do you have access to a feed like RSS, ATOM etc then you could use a feed parser like this one https://github.com/miniflux/picoFeed

Edit: I don't know which technologies you are using, these are for PHP as i think this isn't possible to fully automate with SQL :)